# SumoSelect's select-all option overlaps other options in select drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, sumoselect.js

I have a [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) select drop down in my `CodeIgniter` application and inside that the `select all` option has smaller height as compared to other items, and due to this, `select all` option overlaps other option in the drop down list. I have tried to increase the height of `select-all` option element using `jQuery` but I think the height of `<option>` can not be modified manually. So please tell how to resolve this overlapping issue?

**Code:**

```
<select name="type" id="type" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select a type" class="form-control SlectBox">                          
    <?php foreach($types as $type) { ?>
        <option>$type</option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.asd = $('.SlectBox').SumoSelect({ 
            csvDispCount: 3,
            selectAll: 1,
            captionFormat: '{0} types selected!',
            captionFormatAllSelected:'All {0} types selected!'
        }); 
        <?php if(count(array_filter($Type_list))==0){?>
            $('select.SlectBox')[0].sumo.selectAll();
        <?php } ?>      
    });
</script>
```

**Overlapping Issue:**
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find you find out what it was, if yes please share and answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround. Catch the `opening` event of sumo select and dynamically set the height of first element with jquery.

```
$('#EmployeeType').on('sumo:opening', function () {

    $('.select-all').css('height', '35px');

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this css class and adjust height and padding
.form-group >.SumoSelect.open >.optWrapper>.select-all {height: 50px;padding: 6px 35px;}

Answer (score -1):

As a quick fix in Firefox, this solution worked for me. I added the following style to my css file for the page.

```
.SumoSelect .select-all {
  display: table-cell;
}
```